# How to include jar file as dependency?

Tags: java, jar, compilation, javac

Having this layout:

```
.
├── lib
│   └── Calculator.jar
├── TestLib
│   ├── com
│   │   └── example
│   │       └── util
│   │           ├── Calculator.class
│   │           └── Calculator.java
│   └── manifest.txt
└── TestWeb
    └── com
        └── example
            └── Runner.java
```

`Calculator.java`:

```
package com.example.util;

public class Calculator{
    public int add(int i, int j){
        return i + j;
    }
}
```

`Runner.java`:

```
package com.example;

import com.example.util.Calculator;

public class Runner{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        Calculator c = new Calculator();
        System.out.println(c.add(4, 8));
    }
}
```

I have made jar file from `Calculator.class` into `lib/Calculator.jar`. Now I would like to use the `Calculator` object in `Runner.java` class. So if I issue:

```
javac -cp .:lib/Calculator.jar TestWeb/com/example/Runner.java
```

I got

```
TestWeb/com/example/Runner.java:3: error: package com.example.util does not exist
import com.example.util.Calculator;
                       ^
TestWeb/com/example/Runner.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        Calculator c = new Calculator();
        ^
  symbol:   class Calculator
  location: class Runner
TestWeb/com/example/Runner.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
        Calculator c = new Calculator();
                           ^
  symbol:   class Calculator
  location: class Runner
3 errors
```

What do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The classpath syntax is Operating System dependent. From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Classpath) :

> Being closely associated with the file system, the command-line
> Classpath syntax depends on the operating system.[1] For example:
>
> on all Unix-like operating systems (such as Linux and Mac OS X), the
> directory structure has a Unix syntax, with separate file paths
> separated by a colon (":"). on Windows, the directory structure has a
> Windows syntax, and each file path must be separated by a semicolon
> (";"). This does not apply when the Classpath is defined in manifest
> files, where each file path must be separated by a space (" "),
> regardless of the operating system.

Comment: I am on unix, ubuntu. The problem is not witb separator, but the compiler is not able to find the included library (in jar). See the question one more time.

Comment: `java -cp ./lib/Calculator.jar com.example.util.Calculator` is what you need

Comment: That is the way to include the jar file, but how to use it with the `Runner.java`, where the `main()` function is? The jar file is just helper library

Answer (score 0):

Let me know if I've left anything out you need:

```
goose@t410:/tmp/build$ tree -n
.
├── lib
│   └── Calculator.jar
├── TestLib
│   └── com
│       └── example
│           └── util
│               ├── Calculator.class
│               └── Calculator.java
└── TestWeb
    └── com
        └── example
            ├── Runner.class
            └── Runner.java
```

```
goose@t410:/tmp/build$ java -cp lib/Calculator.jar:TestWeb com.example.Runner
12
goose@t410:/tmp/build$
```

Comment: I already have jar file created. It is in `./lib`. But I cannot somehow compile it with the main class (Runner.java). As `java -cp ./lib/Calculator.jar ./TestWeb/com/example/Runner.java`. Do you understand what I am asking?